# How to call static variable from another form c#?

Tags: c#, constructor, static, mdi

I have MDI parent and few child forms. I want to declare a static variable in MDI parent form, and 'call' it from my child forms.

In particulary I want it to start as 0 (zero) and eventualy give it value 1 or 2.

This is the way I declared my static variable, and I want to know IS THE CODE OK, AND IF NOT WHAT IS WRONG.

```
static class Permission
    {

        static int role;

        public static int GetPermission()
        {
            role = 0;
            return (role);
        }

    }
```

The second and more important question is HOW TO CALL THAT STATIC VARIABLE INSIDE MY CHILD FORM(S). What code should I write and where ?

Thank you all.

Comment: Any time you call `GetPermission` it will return 0.  Is that intended?

Answer (score 0):

You call it via `Permission.GetPermission();` from anywhere within the same project (as it's currently defaulted to an internal class).

Answer (score -2):

Use static class and add {get;set;} to your variable. Also if you want to directly get value - set role visibility to public